# How can I get DML syntax from existing tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ddl, dml

I have several tables in MySQL database and those tables are already filled;

Is there any way to get DML, which fills tables with same name, with exact same data?

for ex. if I have table (names) like this:

```
name_id : 1
name_val : john
name_id : 2
name_val : jack
```

I want to get this kind of DML :

```sql
Insert into table names(name_id,name_val) values(1,'john');
Insert into table names(name_id,name_val) values(2,'jackn');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

To get only data use `--no-create-info` parameter

```
mysqldump -u user -p[password] --no-create-info --compact db_name table_name > dump.sql
```